# VBA: How to check with an if condition if a column's cells (known column number) equal to a value?

Tags: vba, excel

I am new to VBA so it might be a simple question.

Firstly, I search into a sheet to find the column number including the word "TABLES".

Then, I want to check if this column's cells equal to a number between 400 to 450 and when the condition is true I create a print preview.

```
Sub CustomPrint()

Dim Lost As Variant

Lost = TABLES

With ActiveSheet.Range("A1").CurrentRegion
Set c = .Find(Lost, LookIn:=xlValues)
End With

For i = 400 To 450 Step 1
If (ActiveSheet.Columns(c).Value = i) Then ActiveSheet.PrintOut preview:=True
Next

End Sub
```

ActiveSheet.Columns(c).Value = i -> This is where I get the error message.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Will the string `TABLES` be in your header?

Comment: You cannot compare an entire columns value to a single value.  Loop the column and see if the value is between 400 and 450.

Comment: @urdearboy  Yes, it's a header, but it is not on the first row in every worksheet.

Comment: @Scott can you please explain to me how can I "loop the column"

Comment: `For i = 1 to 1000`  `If Activesheet.Cells(i,c.column) >=400 andActivesheet.Cells(i,c.column) <= 450 Then ActiveSheet.PrintOut preview:=True`  `Next I`

Comment: [Option Explicit](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xyVrl.gif)

Comment: @ScottCraner My mistake, I want to create multiple previews, one preview for the column's cells that equal to 401, other preview for cells equal to 402 etc. So this should be in the for condition.

Comment: Then you will need two loops one inside the other.  Put mine inside yours and change the i to j on my code.

Answer (score 2):

I think this will work for you. Once `TOTAL` is found (*string*, not *variant*), it will loop through the row (starting below `TOTAL`) until last row. It will then see if any cell in that range is between 400 | 450 and display print preview when true

```
Sub CustomPrint()

Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")

Dim Found As Range, SearchRange As Range, MyCell As Range, LRow as Long

Set Found = ws.Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Find("TABLES", LookIn:=xlValues)
If Found Is Nothing Then Exit Sub

LRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, Found.Column).End(xlUp).Row
Set SearchRange = ws.Range(ws.Cells(Found.Row + 1, Found.Column), ws.Cells(LRow, Found.Column))

For Each MyCell In SearchRange
    If MyCell > 400 And MyCell < 450 Then
        MyCell.WorkSheet.PrintOut Preview:=True
    End If
Next MyCell

End Sub
```

Comment: I would consider adjusting some of the properties of the `.Find` method. Should this look in the entire cell? Case sensitive? Etc.

Comment: an `Exit For` might reduce repetitious Print Previews.

Comment: @urdearboy thank you very much. My mistake, I want to create multiple previews, one preview for the column's cells that equal to 401, other preview for cells equal to 402 etc. So this should be in the for condition.

Comment: Agh. I assumed that was a mistake. Can fix in a few hours if you don’t have it figured out by then.

Comment: @urdearboy I wish I could figure it out.. but of course I can wait for you. THANK YOU so much!!!

Comment: @urdearboy I've changed the sheet to ActiveSheet like this: Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet
It runs but no preview page is displayed. 
I will explain to you again. I want a preview for each value in SearchRange. I want to print all the rows when the cell in SearchRange equals to 400, then all the rows when the cell in SearchRange equals to 401. I don't think that the condition yCell > 400 And MyCell < 450 is correct because I want each distinct value to be printed in a defferent preview.

Answer (score 0):

since you need a printout for every single matched value, I guess you need the printout area be related to the matching cell:

```
Option Explicit

Sub CustomPrint()
    Dim cell As Range

    On Error GoTo ExitSub
    With Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Find(what:="TABLE", LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole)
        For Each cell In .Resize(.Parent.Cells(Rows.Count, .Column).End(xlUp).Row - .Column + 1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants, xlNumbers)
            If cell.Value2 > 400 And cell.Value2 < 450 Then cell.Resize(20, 20).Offset(-WorksheetFunction.Min(10, cell.Row - 1), -WorksheetFunction.Min(10, cell.Column - 1)).PrintOut preview:=True ' this sort of center the printout to the current cell and its 20x20 surroundings
        Next
    End With

ExitSub:

End Sub
```

Comment: @diadiaki, any feedback?